# PHP - unlink() works with direct path but not a required one

Tags: php, directory, require, unlink

I am using unlink() to delete a PDF file from a directory. In this case, the name of the file is stored in a variable i.e. $fileName. I have tested to make sure the file name in the variable matches the one in the directory.

For some reason it is working with a direct path but not a required one. For example:

**working:**

```
unlink('C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/sample_dir/' . $fileName);
```

**not working:**

```
unlink(require_once __DIR__ . '/../../uploads/sample_dir/' . $fileName);
```

There are no errors thrown, it just does nothing. Oof.

Comment: So, that is trying to unlink by the entire contents returned from the file. Please read up what `require_once` is used for ;)

Comment: `require_once` also returns a status `1` if success so you are actually trying to `unlink(1)` assuming the best senario

Comment: ...oops haha. How do I go about deleting this file without a direct path then? I ask because I see a lot of people saying $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] isn't a good option.

Comment: just use unlink ( _DIR_ .  '/../../uploads/sample_dir/' . $fileName);

Comment: '*facepalms*' that worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you're using Wordpress so just use [`wp_upload_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/).

Answer (score 1):

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'additional path to folder' . $fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, that worked too. I was just attempting to use as little hard coded path as possible.